# Using Ruby variable in Javascript (In App View)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently, I have a ruby variable accessible by the view called `@json` (which contains information I need in JSON format)

However, I want to pass this into a script area such as

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

//Want @json to be usable here

</script>
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the script tag you mentioned is in a html erb view you can just use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var json = <%= @json || 'null' %>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is like this:
var json = "#{ @json || 'null' }"

Answer (score 1):

Better wrap that in quotes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var json = "<%= @json %>";
</script>
```