# Create a variable in Ruby on Rails to use in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Ruby variable in Javascript (In App View)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673227/using-ruby-variable-in-javascript-in-app-view)

is there a way to create a kind of variable in a Ruby on Rails view to use it later in a javascript tag?

I want to do something like that:

```
    <p>
    <%  test=Build.where("result = 1").count(:result) %> of the builds succeeded.
    </p>


<%= javascript_tag do %>

            console.log(test);

<% end %>
```

Is there a way to do that? This is not working.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `console.log(<%= test %>);`  The variable is in eruby context, not JS.  Be sure to quote it unless it is a numeric value.

Comment: Oh, thanks, sorry I thought I already tried that! It works for my bigger problem I guess!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access any ruby variable in an erb with <%= %>

Since you want to show it as a string do

```
console.log('<%= Build.where("result = 1").count(:result) %>');
```

Answer (score 3):

I would move the logic into the controller if possible, take a look at the gon gem too: https://github.com/gazay/gon

**Edit:** I read your question wrong.

```
# Controller
@test = Build.where("result = 1").count(:result)

# View
<%= javascript_tag do %>

    console.log(<%= @test %>);

<% end %>
```