# Accessing Ruby variable inside a Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml

I am new to Javascript. I am writing a view in haml that fills a dropdown box by using JQuery and to fill that box JQuery requires the value of a Ruby variable `s_id` like following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var param = s_id  //here s_id is a ruby variable
  ...
```

Here `s_id` is a ruby variable that is defined in the Haml view file for which the JS get called. Can anyone give any idea how to achieve the above thing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673227/using-ruby-variable-in-javascript-in-app-view `<---this might be helpful`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to directly access the variable. If the JS code is on the same page, you can just add the value using `<%= s_id %>`. I haven't used HAML much, so you would have to adapt it from this ERB code.

Another solution, since your doing it after document.ready is to store the value in a hidden field and then select it from JS `$('#your_sid_field').val()`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to move it to be a partial. Set it up in a file called something like `app/views/whatever/_some_script.js.erb` and then reference it like so:

```
render partial: 'whatever/some_script', locals: { s_id: s_id }
```

In the javascript file, you'll do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var param = <%= s_id %>;
  ...
```

Make sure if it's a string, you put quotes around it. That should be it.

Comment: In my situation, I cannot use partial.

Comment: Why can't you use partials? They are a core Rails feature. As an alternative, you can just include a bit of Javascript in your view template to make that variable accessible by the Javascript on the page.