# I would like to specify the asset_path to a folder with images in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, emoji

I cannot specify a folder with the asset_path helper method, only a picture. I want a url which points to the folder with the pictures so that the tool can find and display these pictures. Any ideas?

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    window.emojiPicker = new EmojiPicker({
      emojiable_selector: '[data-emojiable=true]',
      assetsPath: <%= asset_path('emojis') %>, // <- Path to folder doesn't work, only to a specific image
      popupButtonClasses: 'fa fa-smile-o'
    });
    window.emojiPicker.discover();
  });
</script>
```

Folder structure 'emojis':

```
assets/
  images/
    emojis/
      blank.gif
      emoji.png
      emoji2.png
```

Comment: can you take a look at this stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673227/using-ruby-variable-in-javascript-in-app-view

Comment: I know how to run ruby code in erb files. That was not my question.

Comment: Try `asset_path('/emojis')` (with a leading slash).

Comment: Doesn't work because it expects a picture.

Comment: i moved all images into the /public folder and determined the asset path as follows. 
`"#{request.base_url}/images/emojis"` Now it's working.